# Variable object properties in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object `$var` which has 3 properties `one` `two` `three`. I'm trying to store the properties in an array `$info`.

The long way:

```
$info['one'] = $var->one;
$info['two'] = $var->two;
$info['three'] = $var->three;
```

At some point in the future the 3 properties will become many more so I'm trying to store the properties in my array using a `foreach` loop.

```
$attributes = array( 'one', 'two', 'three' );

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    $info[$attribute] = $var->$attribute; // My problem is here
}
```

The problem I'm having is you can't do this: `$var->$attribute`.

How can I use a variable for my object's property?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to do that? Do you get any errors? The code works fine for me.

Comment: Try `$var->{$attribute}` or I would just do `$info = get_object_vars($var)`.

Comment: @Rizier123 are you saying I **can** do that?

Comment: @henrywright I would say that's the way to do it! (OR use ^ `get_object_vars()` as AbraCadaver mentioned)

Comment: Why can't you use `get_object_vars`? Or you want private properties also (which seems a dangerous design)?

Comment: My `$var` object has so much more to it, info that I don't want in `$info`, so `get_object_vars()` isn't great for my case, but thanks for the tip - I'll keep the function in mind for future

Comment: Then maybe `array_intersect_key` would save you the loop. Or there could be some logic to distinguish between attributes you want and attributes you don't want (and array_filter could help, then).

Comment: So which is right? `$var->{$attribute}` or `$var->$attribute`

Comment: @henrywright : what is Rizier123 saying is that, if what you show is the real word example, your snippet of code **does work properly**. If it does not, that means, you have another problem you are not showing us.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code works fine, or I would just do:

```
$var = new someObj;
$attributes = array( 'one', 'two', 'three' );
$info = array_intersect_key(array_flip($attributes), get_object_vars($var));
```

Comment: what's the difference between `$var->{$attribute}` and `$var->$attribute`?

Comment: On beer 5 I'm going to step away for now :-)